# Ant Design grid: fix width in every page size

Tags: reactjs, antd

is this possible?

this is ant.design docs:

xxl ≥1600px, could be a span value or an object containing above props

that means i can write this:

```js
<Row justify="center">
  <Col xxl={{ flex: "1140px" }} lg={{ flex: "992px" }}>
    Header
  </Col>
</Row>
```

but not working!

Answer (score -1):

`flex` property is a shorthand for `flex-grow` / `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.

If the Row component is a flex container you should be able to use:

```css
flex-grow: 0; /* doesn't grow */
flex-shrink: 0; /* doesn't shrink */
flex-basis: 1140px; /* the size you want it to be */
```

which can be also written:

```css
flex: 0 0 1140px;
```

or in a .js file: `flex: '0 0 1140px'`

if the container isn't flex, simply use the width property instead

Comment: have you tried width ? is Row large enough to contain your 1140px wide element ?

Comment: `Row` and `Col` are Ant Design components and i want to use these components features. and width is not one of features. i think this is a bug in antd!

Comment: Col has a dynamic width based on either `flex` or `span` props, which is not what you want. You have to use a simple div instead of a col and set `flex: '0 0 1140px'` on it

Comment: i think that you don't know ant design, so thank you and please don't do spam